# kivy application is breaking layout when resizing window

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I just installed and configured Kivy, PyGame, Cyphon, Python 3 and everything i needed, when i executed main.py, It started printing warnings:

```
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 220px, got 100px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 220px, got 100px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 220px, got 100px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[INFO   ] [Context     ] Reloading graphics data...
[INFO   ] [Context     ] Reloading done in 0.1813s
 'kivy.graphics.context.Context.dealloc_texture' ignored
 Exception OverflowError: 'signed integer is greater than maximum' in 'kivy.graphics.context.Context.dealloc_texture' ignored
 Exception OverflowError: 'signed integer is greater than maximum' in 'kivy.graphics.context.Context.dealloc_texture' ignored
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
```

Objects wouldn't fit in the small layout, So i had to expand it in order to see everything.
Whenever i resized window, It would print this:

`Exception OverflowError: 'signed integer is greater than maximum' in 'kivy.graphics.context.Context.dealloc_texture' ignored`

and frame would go fully black.

Is there any way to fix this problem? am i missing frameworks? Or is it a bug in Kivy?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: These are the only errors i got.

Comment: I mean your python code that throws these errors so we can test it ourselves

Comment: It requires whole Kivy-designer fie, as i know main.py opens all necessary scripts, However, If you want whole file here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer